# vagrant, nginx, phpmyadmin installation issue

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, vagrant, centos6, vagrantfile

I'm working on creating virtual box for vagrant. With spec below:

```
Host : Windows 7

Guest:
Centos 6.5
PHP 5.5
Mysql 5.6.19
Nginx 1.6.0
PhpMyAdmin 4.2.2
```

In my vagrant file, I set the IP forwarding like this one :

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 80, guest: 80
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 8080
```

In my windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 labs.dev
127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin
```

In my guest OS, i set up nginx configuration file for phpMyAdmin (/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpMyAdmin) like this one :

```
server{
    listen       8080;
    server_name phpmyadmin;

    location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
      client_max_body_size 4M;
      client_body_buffer_size 128k;
      try_files $uri =404;
      root /usr/share/;

      # Point it to the fpm socket;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)) {
      root /usr/share/;
    }
  }
  location /phpMyAdmin {
    rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
  }
}
```

When i hit `http://labs.dev` it works normal, it shows the nginx welcome screen. but when i hit `http://phpmyadmin:8080`, the browser response with "could not connect to `http://phpmyadmin:8080`". I also try `http://phpmyadmin` which is give the same nginx welcome screen instead of phpmyadmin login page. I have tried several configuration but still have no luck. Any advice guys? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suggest maybe looking at firewalls on both sides windows firewall and iptables on centos

5 docs but I guess relevant 
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-iptables.html

Answer (score 1):

Is your root declaration on the nginx config correct?

root /usr/share/

Shouldn't that point to the full path of the phpMyAdmin installation?  Where the index.php main file resides?  I might be wrong but maybe try setting it to "/usr/share/phpmyadmin" and see if that fixes it.

But also like it was mentioned CentOS will turn up the firewall on you and not have port 8080 open.  You might need to open that port.